# How can I fix the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" that has occured after moving my java files in packages?

Tags: java, class, project

Okay, so I'm learning Java, and have just moved all of my test files into different folders, with package headers. Yet the compiler states the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

The class file is clearly there, and yet it cannot find it?

I'm using VS Code is that's any help. The files work in Intellij, but I'm trying to get to know VS Code as it's a good 'all around' editor.

I've looked all over but the symptoms of what others have experienced are different to mine.

```
package loops;

public class EnhancedForLoop {
public static void main(String []args) {
    int [] numbers = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25};
    for(int x : numbers ) {
        System.out.println( x + "," );
    }

    System.out.println("\n");


    String [] names = {"Kettle", "Pot", "Cup", "Jug"};
    for(String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name + ",");
    }
}
}
```

Like I said, this should run fine. But after moving the files it doesn't :(.

The full error message is:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\nickr\Documents\VS Workspace\Project 1\src\loops\" && javac EnhancedForLoop.java && java EnhancedForLoop
Error: Could not find or load main class EnhancedForLoop
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: loops/EnhancedForLoop (wrong name: EnhancedForLoop)
```

Comment: Remove the import statements that refer to your application's classes and reimport them.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the `Code Runner` extension of visual studio code, which doesn't support running java files in packages by default [see issue 487](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/487) seems related. The full language support for java works with this and allows the code to run (when I click on debug it just runs to completion).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use -verbose to see the detail.

```
cd "c:\Users\nickr\Documents\VS Workspace\Project 1\src\loops\" && javac EnhancedForLoop.java && java -verbose EnhancedForLoop
```

I think java could not find the EnhancedForLoop in classpath because of you didn't set the classpath.